# Adding variables to all templates?

Tags: theming

I'm looking for a way to inject a feature flag variable so that it is accessible in all Twig templates, but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried adding variables in preprocessing hooks in my .theme file, but this doesn't seem to do to the trick. For example:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['some_feature_flag'] = 'test_value';
}

function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['some_feature_flag'] = 'test_value;
}
```

My template for the node contains `{{dump(some_feature_flag)}}`, which evaluates to NULL. I can't find a way to get this working.

Comment: did you replace `mytheme` with the actual name of your theme?

Answer (score 5):

So generally, preprocess hooks impact the specific theme item or template, so hook_preprocess_page() impacts the page.html.twig and hook_preprocess_html() does so for html.html.twig.  You mentioned your twig template for node, to add variables to that you would need to implement hook_preprocess_node().

Your question was adding variables to all templates, I believe for that you would use just hook_preprocess() (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/8.2.x) - though I have never tried it.  I imagine it would be called for every theme call so that could create a lot of overhead.

And don't forget to 'Clear all caches' under admin->config->development->performance when you create new preprocess hooks or template files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a variable to every template used from a theme, without implementing more than one preprocess function, you can:

- Implement [`hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/8.3.x) in the theme or in a module
- Implement [`hook_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter(&$variables)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter/8.3.x) in a module

Keep in mind that `hook_preprocess()` is invoked for a theme only when that theme is used for rendering the current page. That doesn't happen for modules; so, if those variables you are trying to set should be available to more than one theme, then it would be better to implement one of those hooks in a module.